# Initializing a Class that Utilizes Constructor with IntPtr

Tags: c#, namespaces, intptr, cscore

All, I'm new to C# and I'm trying to work through a problem that I'm having a hard time understanding.

I'm referencing a library in my code (which I've successfully added to my references). I've also identified the specific namespace within the library to bring in. However, when I initialize an instance of a class within said namespace I'm running into some issues.

The class in question has a constructor (I believe) that has an IntPtr argument. When I'm initializing an instance of the class in my code it's expecting me to provide it with an IntPtr argument, but I don't understand what exactly I should be providing. I know that IntPtr is a pointer to a space in memory, but what that means in my code I'm not sure.

Here is a link to the Library in question: https://github.com/filoe/cscore
The Namespace/Class in reference is in my code below.

```
using System;
using CSCore.CoreAudioAPI;

namespace EndpointController_POC_v0._1
{
   class Program
   {
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
        AudioEndpointVolume endPtCtrl = new AudioEndpointVolume(?);

        endPtCtrl.SetMasterVolumeLevelScalar(1, Guid.Empty);
        Console.ReadLine();

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You should really focus this to the project in question, or at least tag it here

Comment: @saruman thanks for the heads up, how can I do that? I updated the tags to include CSCore which is what I'm assuming you meant.

Comment: Anyone have any further suggestions here? I’ve been researching and trying to understand what’s going on here but still not reaching a resolution. I’ve been exploring other libraries but not having much luck.